# ld: framework not found FacebookAdapter

Tags: ios, react-native, admob, facebook-ads

after install [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-admob-native-ads) library in a react-native project I have got this error.

```
ld: framework not found FacebookAdapter
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I have these lines in **pod** file

```
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook'
```

but still have issues. I have downgrade the

```
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
pod 'GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook'
```

to lower version and tried multiple lower versions  then I got these errors

```
Showing Recent Messages
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GADAdLoader

Showing Recent Messages
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GADMultipleAdsAdLoaderOptions

Showing Recent Messages
Undefined symbol: OBJC_METACLASS$_GADNativeAdView

Showing Recent Messages
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GADCustomEventExtras

Showing Recent Messages
Undefined symbol: _GADSimulatorID

Showing Recent Messages
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GADCustomEventExtras

Showing Recent Messages
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GADNativeAdMediaAdLoaderOptions

Showing Recent Messages
Undefined symbol: OBJC_CLASS$_GADNativeAdViewAdOptions
```